# Why is $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1},w^{\pm 1}] \cong (\mathbb{C}^{*})^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Why is $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1},w^{\pm 1}] \cong (\mathbb{C}^{*})^4$?

I'm trying to get a basic understanding of this $\operatorname{Spec}$ after reading a bit of algebraic geometry from Dummit and Foote. So, $\operatorname{Spec}$ is going to give us all the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1},z^{\pm 1},w^{\pm 1}]$... Is this because a prime ideal is of the form $\langle cx^{\pm 1} \rangle$ for $c \in \mathbb{C}$? Thanks

Comment: You mean the maximal  ideals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the simpler case of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}])$. Note that we have the $\mathbb C$-algebra isomorphism
$$
\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}]=\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}] \cong \mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1).
$$
Now $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is the coordinate ring of the variety in $\mathbb C^2$ given by $xy=1$. However, this variety is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^*$ by the isomorphism $V(xy-1)\to\mathbb C^*$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$. In this way $\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}]$ becomes the coordinate ring of $\mathbb C^*$, in other words $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}]) = \mathbb C^*$.

Comment: Then $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]/(I(X),J(Y))= \Bbb{C}[ V(I) \times V(J)]$

Comment: What about the generic point? I think this only works for the maximal spectrum, since there isn't a point in $\mathbb{C}^*$ corresponding to the zero ideal.

Comment: @RichardD.James At the level of my answer, $\operatorname{Spec}(R)=V$ just means that $V$ is the affine variety with coordinate ring $R$, so maximal ideals of $R$ correspond to points in $V$. If you want an interpretation where $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is the spectrum of a ring in the sense of prime ideals, you'd have to at least go to the level of affine schemes and see how both $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}])$ and $\mathbb C^*$ are considered locally ringed spaces. Then $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x^{\pm 1}])\cong \mathbb C^*$ is a canonical isomorphism of affine schemes.

Comment: However, the statement in OPs question looks a lot like something you'd see in an introduction to toric varieties, where scheme theory is overkill and the point of view taken in my answer is enough to get going.